# "Trailing Ones" Primality Conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I've been working on proving a conjecture I came up with a day or so ago but am having trouble getting off the ground. Here's the idea:

---

> Define the *trailing-ones number* of a number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ to be the fewest number of 1's that must be added to the end of the number to make it prime.

---

For instance, the number $23$ has a trailing-ones number of $0$ because it is already prime without any ones being added to the end of it. On the other hand, the number $45$ has a trailing-ones number of $772$, because while $45$ is not prime, $45$ followed by 772 ones *is* a prime number. Moreover, any number of trailing ones $< 772$ after $45$ will not produce a prime number.

My conjecture is as follows:

---

> Every natural number has a finite trailing-ones number.

---

That is, there exists no natural number that cannot be made prime by adding some finite number of 1's to the end of it.

What tools come to mind that I could use to prove this conjecture? Do you think this conjecture is false? If so, can you provide a counterexample? One particular example of note is that of $n=38$, which I have yet to compute the trailing-ones number of because it seems to be significantly greater than a thousand.

Comment: An integer $n$ with $k$ digits, last of which is $1$, is a prime with probability inversely proportional to $\ln n$ which is more or less a constant times $k$. Because the harmonic series diverges, we would expect there to be infinitely primes in such a sequence. But, I'm not a number theorist. This was just a kind a heuristic. I've been told that surprisingly often primes do follow such heuristics, but proving it in this case is a much taller order :-)

Comment: This seems like an exceedingly difficult conjecture to prove. Very intriguing question. I do hope this gets upvotes so that more people see it.

Comment: In fact, $38$ is the smallest hard case.

Comment: @Peter Definitely is. 38 is very hard, but I've noticed something. Adding $3k+1$ ones always results in a multiple of 3, adding $3k+2$ ones always results in a multiple of 37, so we only need to think about adding $3k$ ones, no? EDIT: I believe 38 is actually a valid counterexample! Adding $3k$ ones is always a multiple of $23\cdots3$ (2 followed by $k$ 3's).

Comment: Etiquette on MSE would ask you to post your edit as an answer to your own question and then accept it.

Comment: @Peter in my edit I propose a covering system for $38$. Only missing rigor for the final case of $3k$ ones.

Comment: @Ian my counterexample is not yet totally proven for the case of $3k$ ones. But when it is, I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: $$38111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111$$ has smallest prime factor $444007$ , but beginning with $371$ we seem to have always a very small prime factor.

Comment: Nice question & solution!

Comment: @Peter Two of the prime factors, 11661407 × 2000902063819 = 23333333333333333333

Comment: @Ian No, updates should be made in the body of the question. Unless there is a complete solution for the problem , found by the author.

Comment: [this](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000000298297059) example seems to exhibit algebraic factors

Comment: So, maybe $38$ is a "nontrivial" counterexample.

Comment: Counterexcamples follow easily by standard applications of covering arguments - see the linked dupe (and its links). Please search for answers before posing questions to help avoid duplication.

Comment: Please don't put *answers* into the question - this is against SE policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we begin with $371$ , we never arrive at a prime :

- If we add $6k$ ones ($k$ non-negative integer) , we have prime factor $7$
- If we add $6k+3$ ones , we have prime factor $13$
- If we add $3k+1$ ones , we have prime factor $3$
- If we add $3k+2$ ones , we have prime factor $37$

Hence $[3,7,13,37]$ is a complete covering system.

Comment: great work! thank you for your answer

Comment: what about $6k+5$ though?

Comment: @Mike Typos, thank you for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: Nice answer! I knew from your answer that if $6k+1$ ones gave a prime factor of $3$ then $6k+4$ ones would also give a prime factor $3$, and as $37|111$ , I should have seen that $6k+5$ as well as $6k+2$ gives a prime factor $37$...

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).